# Is $1.0000\cdots 0001$ equal to $1$

Tags: limits

I was wondering if this is true:

$$1.\underbrace{0000\dots0000}_{\infty}1 = 1$$

I tried expressing this as a limit, but I have no idea how to continue:

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}1+10^{x}$$

Also, I'm not so experienced with limits, etc.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.999...

Comment: (The duplicate asks about "existence", but the answers - mine and others - deal with this equality as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been pointed out in the comments, this "number" does not exist within $\mathbb{R}$. However, you say that you are stuck with the limits. So I will tell you how to solve the limit:

To solve the limit issue, use the following fact$^{\dagger}$.

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f+g=\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f+\lim_{x\rightarrow c} g$.

Here, $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}0.1^x=0$, so you go:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}1+0.1^x=1$$
This is the same as you have, but I rather like going to $+\infty$.

Of course, this just says that $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}1+0.1^x=1$, *not* that $0.\underbrace{00000\cdots00}_{\infty}1=1$

---

$^\dagger$See, for example, Theorem 2 of section 1.2 (p67) of Adams *Calculus: A complete course*.

Comment: This is not true. $1+\frac1{10}^x$ is not the same as having infinitely many $0$ and then $1$.

Comment: @Asaf True, but I supposed (perhaps incorrectly) that the OP knew this and answered their limit question. Their actual "number" makes no sense, so working within the reals this is really ($\mathbb{R}$eally) the only answer. Unless I am missing something?

Comment: No, the correct answer is that this is not a real number at all, nor it defines one. (See the discussions in the suggested duplicate.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sure, but it depends on how you want to interpret the question. You want to do some serious, high-level maths. I am sitting drinking a cup of coffee and just wanted to point out to someone how to determine a limit (which they say they were stuck with). So I will edit my answer to make this clear.

Comment: @Integrator sure, but both I and you answered this question a full 10 minutes before the duplicate was pointed out. So [how was I to know](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Is+1.0000%E2%8B%AF0001+equal+to+1)?!?

Comment: Alan, asking about the limit is one thing, but since the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\frac1{10^n}\neq1.\underbrace{0\ldots0}_{\infty\ 0\text{'s}}1$, this is not the right answer to the question.

Comment: @Asaf Yes, I know. I originally would have made this a comment, but lack the rep. However, I do not really understand the issue here, in the sense that the linked answers answer the high-level question, and this answer points out how to solve the OPs (flawed) interpretation using limits. I help with the OPs step 2, and you and others help with the ambient question (step 1).